# iOS 14 - need to programmatically hide new date picker widget

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use the new calendar widget associated with the date picker in Compact style. This is for a number of Enterprise apps that I have written and maintained for several years. In this mode, the Date Picker presents a real nice calendar view instead of that bulky spinner style.

Once a date is selected, the user must tap somewhere outside the widget to make it go away. There is nothing that indicates a user must do this to make it disappear, and I know that this will cause some confusion for my field users. I need to find a way to programmatically hide the widget once the user has selected the date.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I don't think so. I'd suggest filing a bug / enhancement with Apple. They have not really thought this through very well. There have already been some questions here about the converse situation, where you want to use a compact date picker and programmatically present the calendar interface (and you can't).

Comment: @matt Thanks, that's what I expected. Until this changes, I'll just have to go back to the spinner.